# Fastest way to convert videos (batch or single)?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codecs, video-conversion

I know there are a lot of questions about video encoders around here, but my question is more about workflow/efficiency.

For my day job, I need to convert videos, frequently, from many random formats (usually large [AVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Interleave), [M4V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4V), and what not) and convert them and compress them down into efficient files we can use around the internet for uploading. Formats I must produce are:

- WMV ([Windows Media Video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Video) 9)
- [MOV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickTime_File_Format) ([H.264](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC))
- [MP4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14) (H.264)

I need to create common templates for a couple use cases (convert to same-as-source, [1080p](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1080p), or [720p](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/720p)) and be able to process these quickly, and en queue.

Any ideas on how to best go about this process in Ubuntu?

Comment: I know there's Avanti in Windows, and I think the closest you can get in Linux is either the [avconv](http://libav.org/avconv.html) command line or a frontend like WinFF or [ConvertMe](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=153277)... maybe as a last resort you could attempt Avanti in Wine.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you prefer command-line you can use `ffmpeg` (or `handbrake-cli`).

#### MP4

Assuming you're using a recent version of `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium -c:a aac -b:a 128k \
-movflags +faststart -vf scale=-2:720,format=yuv420p output.mp4
```

- `-crf`: Quality. Range is logarithmic 0 (lossless) to 51 (worst quality). Default is 23. Subjective sane range is ~18-28 or so. Use the highest value that still gives you an acceptable quality. If you are re-encoding impractically large inputs to upload to YouTube or similar then try a value of 17 or 18 since these video services will re-encode anyway.
- `-preset`: Encoding speed. A slower preset provides better compression (quality per file size) but is slower. Use the slowest that you have patience for: ultrafast, superfast, veryfast, faster, fast, medium (the default), slow, slower, veryslow.
- `-movflags +faststart`: Allows video to playback before it is completely downloaded in the case of progressive download viewing. Useful if you are hosting the video, otherwise superfluous if uploading to a video service like YouTube.
- `-vf scale=-2:720,format=yuv420p`: A [filtergraph](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-description) using [scale](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) and [format](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) video filters. Scale to 720 pixels in height, and automatically choose width that will preserve aspect, and then make sure the pixel format is compatible with dumb players.
- `-b:a 128k`: Audio bitrate. If your `ffmpeg` is outdated then you'll need to add `-strict experimental` to use `-c:a aac`.

#### MOV

Since your MOV and MP4 files probably contain the same video and audio formats you can encode the MP4 and make the MOV by re-muxing (with [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode) instead of re-encoding:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -codec copy output.mov
```

#### WMV

FFmpeg only supports WMV 7 and 8. I am unaware of an open source encoder for version 9.

```
$ ffmpeg -encoders | grep -i windows
[...]
 V..... = Video
 A..... = Audio
 ------
 V..... wmv1                 Windows Media Video 7
 V..... wmv2                 Windows Media Video 8
 A..... wmav1                Windows Media Audio 1
 A..... wmav2                Windows Media Audio 2
```

As I am unfamiliar with these encoders I can only give an untested example:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v wmv2 -b:v 1024k -c:a wmav2 -b:a 192k output.wmv
```

#### Getting ffmpeg

You can download a [Linux build of ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) or follow a step-by-step [ffmpeg compilation guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) to customize your build.

#### Using a bash "for loop" to perform a batch encode

To encode all videos in a directory:

```
$ mkdir encoded
$ for f in *.avi; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium \
  -c:a aac -b:a 128k -movflags +faststart -vf scale=-2:720,format=yuv420p \
  "encoded/${f%.avi}.mp4"; done
```

#### Also see

- [Who can tell me the difference and relation between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017)
- [FFmpeg H.264 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)
- [FFmpeg AAC Audio Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC)
- [Using HandBrakeCLI](https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/cli/command-line-reference.html)

Answer (score 5):

Try [HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr/).

HandBrake is a tool for converting video from nearly any format to a selection of modern, widely supported codecs.  To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install handbrake
```