# Batch Convert MP4 with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codecs, mp4, video-conversion

I have a whole bunch of text files, jpg and mp4 in a folder. I want the jpg and text files to be left alone. I want to compress all the mp4 using ffmpeg's `-crf` argument with a value of `23`, to save disk space. Files should be overwritten in place.

I used @llogan answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/352920/fastest-way-to-convert-videos-batch-or-single), and replaced `.avi` with `.mp4` but that does not work.

```
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium \
  -c:a aac -b:a 128k -movflags +faststart -vf scale=-2:720,format=yuv420p \
  "encoded/${f%.avi}.mp4"; done
```

What would the `for` loop be to convert mp4 to lower quality (`-crf 23`), in place, without deleting and/or modifying any other files in the same working directory? I don't really want the other flags either, because I won't be doing resizing, youtube uploading, changing encoding speed, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just needed to change `"encoded/${f%.avi}.mp4"` to `"encoded/${f%.mp4}.mp4"` or `"encoded/${f%.*}.mp4"`:

```
mkdir encoded
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium -c:a copy -movflags +faststart "encoded/${f%.*}.mp4"; done
```

I removed all of the other stuff you didn't need. I assumed your input audio is already AAC so I used `-c:a copy` to enable [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode which is like a copy and paste.

`-crf 23 -preset medium` are the default so you can remove those if you are fine with those values. Otherwise, see [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for guidance on what `-crf` and `-preset` values to use.

Comment: can you add a second part to your answer, that would cover cases where you want to overwrite the existing files in place? Please keep the first part of your answer as-is. That is the best practice I'd say.

Comment: @JasonHunter ffmpeg can't perform in-place overwriting of the same input/output. You have to make a new, separate file.

Comment: is there a command I could tack onto the end to "in essence" perform the same task? something like `&& mv /encoded/* /..* --overwrite TRUE`

Comment: @JasonHunter `... "encoded/${f%.*}.mp4"; && mv encoded/*.mp4 .; done`